# Custom graphics in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

I am trying to add the below "graphic" to a chart I am doing in R.

[image]

I could easily do the graphic in a graphics application and then 'glue' it together with the R graph. However, it could be cool to make everything in R since it has the caveat that the position of the black arrow depends on calculated number. In the below case 6.8.

Any suggestions on how I could trick R to produce something like this?

Comment: You've put a ggplot2 tag to this question. Does this need to be ggplot2 or would base graphics acceptable?

Comment: R has plenty of primitive plotting functions. you can draw `lines()` and `polygon()`s and `text()`. There is also the `grid` package with lots of options for drawing. Right now the question is really to broad to be specifically answered. Have you tried anything? It's easier to ask about where specifically you are getting stuck.

Comment: @MrFlick I have not tried anything thus far as had no good idea on how to start. Tried googling around but found nothing that helped me out. Now I have some pointers to go at and that was what I hope to get :-)

Comment: @Bernhard Any solution within R is perfectly acceptable :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a start for a function in base graphics:

```
draw <- function(x){
    plot(NA, xlim=c(0,7), ylim=c(-.3,1), xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="")
    lines(x=c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,0), 
      y=rep(c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0)))
    lines(c(0,7),c(1,1))
    for(i in 1:7) text(x = i-0.5, y= 0.5, labels=i)
    arrows(0, 1.5, 7, 1.5, code=3)
    polygon(x -1 +c(-.1, 0, .1),c(-.3,-0.05,-.3), col="black")
}
draw(4)
draw(3)
```

If you are interested in a base graphics function, you will probably want to make the width:heigth ratio fixed an change my polygon-triangle into a proper arrow, add some more text and things, but this should get you started:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the ggplot2 solution:

```
df_nums <- data.frame(number <- 1:7,
                      fill <- c(rep("white", 5), "darkblue", "white"),
                      color <- c(rep("black", 5), "white", "black"))

df_text <- data.frame(label = c("Lower Risk", "Higher Risk", "Typically Lower Rewards",
                                "Typically Higher Rewards"),
                      hjust = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                      x = c(0, 7, 0, 7),
                      y = c(2.9, 2.9, 2.1, 2.1))

arrow_x_pos <- 6.8 # position of arrow

p1 <- ggplot(df_nums) + 
  geom_tile(aes(x = number - .5, y = 1, fill = fill), size = 1, color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(x = number - .5, y = 1, color = color, label = number), size = 8) +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "none") + scale_fill_identity(guide = "none") +
  geom_text(data = df_text, aes(x = x, y = y, label = label, hjust = hjust), size = 5.5,
            fontface = "bold") +
  geom_text(aes(label = "Risk and Reward Profile", x = 0, y = 3.5),
            fontface = "bold", size = 6.5, hjust = 0) +
  geom_segment(x = 0, xend = 7, y = 2.5, yend = 2.5, size = 1,
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(10,"pt"), ends = "both"),
               color = "grey70") +
  geom_segment(x = arrow_x_pos - 1, xend = arrow_x_pos - 1, y = -.3, yend = .2, size = 4,
               arrow = arrow(length = unit(7, "pt"), type = "closed"),
               lineend = "butt", linejoin = "mitre") +
  ylim(-.2, 3.6) +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_void()
p1
```

[image]